# How can / should I initialize and properly use the `struct`?

Tags: c++, data-structures, refactoring, initialization, arduino

I am programming [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) and I am trying to refactoring code from

```
char variable1[10] = {'\0' };
char variable2[10] = {'\0' };
char variable3[10] = {'\0' };
```

to

```
struct set {
  char variable1[10];
  char variable2[10];
  char variable3[10];
} mySet;
```

However, when I try to initialize a member of the above `struct` by running the following code

```
mySet.variable1 = {'\0' };
// or
mySet.variable1 = '\0';
```

then I get the following error:

```
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token
```

How can / should I initialize and properly use the `struct`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is as follows:

```
struct set {
  char variable1[10];
  char variable2[10];
  char variable3[10];
} mySet = {{'\0'}, {'\0'}, {'\0'}};
```

Of course in C++ you can use `0` instead of `'\0'`, so you can write it in a more readable way:

```
struct set {
  char variable1[10];
  char variable2[10];
  char variable3[10];
} mySet = {{0}, {0}, {0}};
```

Finally, since this is C++, there's no reason not to give your `struct` a constructor, so if you plan to initialize many such structures, you can use the default constructor:

```
set()
: variable1({0})
, variable2({0})
, variable3({0}) {
}
```

Comment: What are other ways (for example in order to initialize the `struct` by using code as-like `mySet.variable1 = <...> `)? Why I should initialize the `struct` by using `struct set {...} mySet = {{0}, {0}, {0}};` instead of `mySet.variable1 = <...> `?

Comment: Why is there no reason not to give your struct a constructor? Where I can read more about?

Comment: @Backo When you write `mySet.variable1 = ...`, it's no longer initialization, it's an assignment. You initialize the `struct` as the whole, not its individual members one at a time.

Comment: @Backo There's [constructors page of the C++FAQ-Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/ctors.html), lots of good info there.

Comment: @Backo the problem you are running into is that you cannot assign to plain C-style arrays. But you could make your life easier by using `std::array<char,10>` instead. That type is assignable and has no overhead compared to a plain array.

Comment: @juanchopanza Officially, at least, it means that he cannot use the elements directly in a C interface.  And he's certainly using a C interface; otherwise, the variables would probably be `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be simply:

```
set mySet = {};
```

.  Alternatively, you might want to define a constructor for
`set`, which ensures that you cannot not initialize it:

```
struct set
{
    //  ...
    set() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Note, however, that if you do this, you can no longer use
aggregate initialization; i.e.

```
set mySet = { "abc", "xyz", "123" };
```

will no longer be legal.

(And of course, you don't want to use the name `set`, because
someone will come along later and do `using namespace std;`, and
expect to get `std::set`.  Avoid the names in the standard
library if you can.)